# How to add protected methods returning non-Windows Runtime types to a C++/WinRT base class

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I got the following C++/CX code that works as intended but would like to convert it to C++/WinRT code:

```
namespace My.Custom.Stuff
{
  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
  public ref class BaseClass : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel
  {
  public:
    BaseClass();
    void PublicMethod();

  protected:
    static ::DirectX::XMFLOAT3 ProtectedMethod();
  };
}


namespace My.Custom.Stuff
{
  [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
  public ref class SubClass sealed : public BaseClass
  {
  public:
    SubClass();
    void UseProtectedMethod()
    {
      ::DirectX::XMFLOAT3 value = ProtectedMethod()
      // ...
    }
  };
}
```

However, the problem that I encounter is as follows: `BaseClass` contains a protected method that returns a type that cannot be mapped to a corresponding Windows Runtime type. In C++/CX this is not a problem because `ProtectedMethod` is not mapped at all. If I use my Windows Runtime component `ProtectedMethod` is simply not exposed which is what I want.

However, that method should be a member of `BaseClass` because multiple other classes like `SubClass` use the method when implementing their public methods. I have come up with the following C++/WinRT MIDL code:

```
namespace My.Custom.Stuff
{
  unsealed runtimeclass BaseClass : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel
  {
    BaseClass();
    void PublicMethod();

    // This does not work
    protected DirectX.XMFLOAT3 RgbFromBrush(IInspectable brush);
  }
}



import "BaseClass.idl";


namespace My.Custom.Stuff
{
  runtimeclass SubClass : BaseClass
  {
    SubClass();
    void UseProtectedMethod();
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I define `ProtectedMethod` that way it won't work because `::DirectX::XMFLOAT3` is no Windows Runtime type. If I use any other return type that protected method gets mapped. However, it should not be visible when using that Windows Runtime component and of course I should not have to change its return type.

How can I achieve what I do with C++/CX using C++/WinRT?

**Edit**

Compiling the MIDL code results in something like this:

```
#include "BaseClass.g.h"


namespace winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::implementation
{
  struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass>
  {
    BaseClass() = default;
    // ...
  };
}


namespace winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::factory_implementation
{
  struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass, implementation::BaseClass>
  {
  };
}
```

I thought it might be possible to simply add the protected method as follows:

```
namespace winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::implementation
{
  struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass>
  {
    BaseClass() = default;

  protected:
    static ::DirectX::XMFLOAT3 ProtectedMethod();
  };
}
```

However, attempting to use `ProtectedMethod` in `SubClass` results in the following error:

```
error C2039: 'ProtectedMethod': is not a member of 'winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::BaseClass'
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
#include "SubClass.g.h"


namespace winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::implementation
{
  struct SubClass : SubClassT<SubClass>
  {
    SubClass() = default;
    void UseProtectedMethod()
    {
      ::DirectX::XMFLOAT3 value = ProtectedMethod();
    }
  };
}


namespace winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::factory_implementation
{
  struct SubClass : SubClassT<SubClass, implementation::SubClass>
  {
  };
}
```

Comment: In your implementation type you are ultimately free to do anything you want (including deriving from a base class that's internal to the implementation). MIDL is designed to describe the public API surface.

Comment: That's what I assumed. However, I'm unable to add the method to a place where `SubClass` can find it. I've added more clarifications to my question. From what I see in the posted error message it's a mismatch of namespaces. I'm adding the method in the *::implementation namespace but it looks for the method outside of it.

Comment: Your thought that simply adding the `ProtectedMethod()` in BaseClass is right. I try the way in my side and the `ProtectedMethod()` can be called successfully in `UseProtectedMethod()` of `SubClass`. Could you please provided the code of calling `ProtectedMethod()` for us to test?

I use `ProtectedMethod()` in `SubClass` like this: `void SubClass::UseProtectedMethod()` `{   ProtectedMethod();   }`
And call the `SubClass.UseProtectedMethod()` like this: `SubClass sc;` `sc.UseProtectedMethod();`

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I',ve added the example that shows how I'm attempting to use the method. Nothing special, seems to be just what you are proposing. I'm getting the impression that this could be related to the fact that I'm using nested namespaces (`My::Custom::Stuff`). However, this is a gut feeling and I don't have an idea what to look for exactly.

Comment: I think this may work: `struct BaseImpl { protected: ::DirectX::XMFLOAT3 ProtectedMethod(); }; struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass>, BaseImpl { ... }; struct SubClass : SubClassT<SubClass>, BaseImpl { ... }`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried that approach but `SubClass` is simply unable to find `BaseImpl` even though they are both defined in namespace `winrt::My::Custom::Stuff::implementation`. Do you have a full working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting from C++/CX to C++/WinRT, only public methods should go into your IDL file, as those are the only methods comprising the WinRT API surface.

Methods that are private/protected/internal are not part of the WinRT API surface, and so they should not go into the IDL.

The usage code you posted shouldn't compile, because your C++ definition of `implementation::SubClass` is missing a template parameter. Since the IDL/WinRT definition has `SubClass` deriving from `BaseClass`, you need to supply `BaseClass`'s implementation type to `SubClassT`, and if you examine the contents of the cppwinrt-generated "SubClass.h", you'll see this happening. Once you declare your implementation of `SubClass` correctly, you will have access to the protected methods on `BaseClass`.

I just tried this out successfully, and it looks like this:

### BaseClass.idl

```cs
namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    [default_interface]
    unsealed runtimeclass BaseClass
    {
        BaseClass();
        void PublicMethod();
    }
}
```

### BaseClass.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "BaseClass.g.h"

struct non_winrt_type
{

};

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass>
    {
        BaseClass() = default;
        void PublicMethod() {}

    protected:
        non_winrt_type ProtectedMethod()
        {
            return {};
        }
    };
}
namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::factory_implementation
{
    struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass, implementation::BaseClass>
    {
    };
}
```

### SubClass.idl

```cs
import "BaseClass.idl";

namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass SubClass : BaseClass
    {
        SubClass();
        void UseProtectedMethod();
    }
}
```

### SubClass.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "SubClass.g.h"
#include "BaseClass.h"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    // Notice how BaseClass is used here.
    // This was copied directly from the generated boilerplate SubClass.h
    struct SubClass : SubClassT<SubClass, RuntimeComponent1::implementation::BaseClass>
    {
        SubClass() = default;

        void UseProtectedMethod()
        {
            auto result = ProtectedMethod();
        }
    };
}
namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::factory_implementation
{
    struct SubClass : SubClassT<SubClass, implementation::SubClass>
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: I attempted to recreate your sample and it worked as you described it. However, this is what I also attempted in my migration project and it just didn't work. So, I went out looking for the difference. In my migration project I have 4 nested namespaces, e.g. `My.Custom.Super.WindowsRuntimeComponent`. Your sample works well if I have 3 or less namespaces but with 4 namespaces the tooling starts changing the name of the generated file `BaseClass.g.h` to `My.Custom.Super.WindowsRuntimeComponent.BaseClass.g.h`. But that currently happens in my newly created sample only, not in my migration project

Comment: Something strange is going on. My migration project only compiles if the `::implementation` part of the namespace is *not* added before `BaseClass` in `struct BaseClass : BaseClassT<BaseClass, implementation::BaseClass>`. More digging is required to get to the bottom of this...

Comment: Alright, so besides the name changes of the generated files I missed adding `#include BaseClass.h` in `SubClass.h`. Instead I removed the `::implementation` part of the namespace. Correcting this and factoring in the changed filenames solves my problem. Thanks a lot for your help, Ryan!